# How to take different actions based on HTTP response code, with Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel's (2.15.x) HTTP4 component and hitting an external web service. Sometimes the responses are `200`, sometimes they are `422`, and sometimes they are `500`. For the `200`s, I'm good. My problem is that I want to retry when I get the `500` but not when I get the `422`. In both cases, it's an `HttpOperationFailedException`. I've looked at the Camel documentation and Googled but I've not found any examples of how to do this. Any advice, or URLs, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap it all in a try catch expression similar to normal java and do it with the Camel dsl.

```
.doTry()
  .to("your_http_endpoint")
.doCatch(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
  .choice()
  .when(header(HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isEqualTo("500"))
    .to("do your retry or whatever you want to do")
  .otherwise()
    .to("somewhere_else when its not 500")
.end();
```

Comment: Minor change - should be `.when(header(HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isEqualTo("500"))` as `when()` requires a `Predicate` not a boolean

Comment: can you please show how you implemented retry logic?? i have similar problem but my http requests are also load balanced with failover load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i would do in your scenario. Implement a custom `Processor` in your route definition, right after the `HTTP4`. This will allow you to inspect the response and more importantly the response status code. After that, it would be on you to define how to proceed, based on the status code.

Something like this (semi-pseudo):

```
from("http4://SOME_URL").process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message out = exchange.getOut();
        int responseCode = out.getHeader(HttpProducer.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
        //HERE DECIDE WHAT TO DO BASED ON YOUR RESPONSE CODE!
   }
}).to("some_other_endpoint");
```

Look at the section "Getting the Response Code" [here](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/http4.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a [MessageRouter](http://camel.apache.org/message-router.html) pattern. The camel DSL provides for a 'choice' that allows for 'when'->'to' and 'otherwise'->'to' which I think will suffice for what you are looking for.